# Wrap method implementations of Java interfaces

Tags: java, methods, wrapper, spring-aop

I have multiple interfaces each defining multiple methods as below:

```
public interface X {
    void methodX1;

    void methodX2(String s);
}

public interface Y {
    void methodY1;

    void methodY2(int i);

    void methodY3(SomeType s);
}

....
```

Currently the method implementation looks like this:

```
public class XImpl implements X {
        public void methodX1() {
            // method implementation
        }
    }
```

For every implementation of the interface, I need to wrap the method implementation with a `try-with-resource` block as below:

```
public class XImpl implements X {
    public void methodX1() {
        try (SomeResource res = new SomeResource()) {
            // method implementation
        }
    }
}
```

With my limited notion of AOP, I believe we can do things before and after the `JoinPoint` i.e. method in this case, but how can we wrap implementation as above? I am looking to see if it can be done using annotations or lambda, i.e. something where I do not have to go changing each method individually.

Any thought on how this can be done will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an AOP library, eg AspectJ?

Comment: If you have many concrete classes implementing X you can write a single proxy class to add that aspect -- but that will still require an implementation for each method on the interface. You could also roll your own AOP using java.lang.reflect.Proxy, which would not require any repetition. Or as @Bohemian suggests, use an existing AOP library.

Comment: It'll be dependent on the architecture used: container-based, compiler-time resolution / runtime resolution... Thinking about it, you won't have to change each method but you'll still have to add the annotation to each method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With my limited notion of AOP, I believe we can do things before and after the JoinPoint i.e. method in this case, but how can we wrap implementation as above?

Have you ever read the very good [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)? One of the first things you would notice would be the explanation of advice types and that there is not only before and after, but also **around advice**. This is what you want to use.

Here is basically how it works:

**Java helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class SomeType {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class SomeResource implements AutoCloseable {
  @Override public void close() throws Exception {}
}
```

**Interfaces:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface X {
  void methodX1();
  int methodX2(String s);
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface Y {
  void methodY1();
  String methodY2(int i);
  void methodY3(SomeType s);
}
```

**Interface implementation + driver application:**

I implemented the example in AspectJ, not in Spring AOP. Thus you see no application context, but you know how to do that, don't you?

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyImpl implements X, Y {
  @Override public void methodY1() { System.out.println("Y1"); methodX2("bar"); }
  @Override public String methodY2(int i) { System.out.println("Y2"); return "dummy"; }
  @Override public void methodY3(SomeType s) { System.out.println("Y3"); }
  @Override public void methodX1() { System.out.println("X1"); methodY1(); }
  @Override public int methodX2(String s) {  System.out.println("X2"); return 42; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyImpl myImpl = new MyImpl();
    myImpl.methodX1();
    myImpl.methodX2("foo");
    myImpl.methodY1();
    myImpl.methodY2(11);
    myImpl.methodY3(new SomeType());
  }
}
```

Please note that both `methodX1()` and `methodY1()` call methods internally. This will be important with regard to the difference between Spring AOP and AspectJ later.

**Aspect:**

In Spring AOP you can omit the `execution(* *(..)) &&` part, I just use it here in order to avoid other joinpoints such as `call()` being intercepted and the log to get bloated. As Spring AOP does not know much else than `execution()` it is not necessary there. The parentheses around the `... || ...` block of the pointcut can also go away.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.scrum_master.app.SomeResource;

@Component
@Aspect
public class WrapMethodsAspect {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && (within(de.scrum_master.app.X+) || within(de.scrum_master.app.Y+))")
  public Object wrapperAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Wrapping " + thisJoinPoint);
    try (SomeResource res = new SomeResource()) {
      return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
      System.out.println("Unwrapping " + thisJoinPoint);
    }
  }
}
```

**Console output with AspectJ:**

```
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.main(String[]))
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX1())
X1
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Y1
Wrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
X2
Unwrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX1())
Wrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
X2
Unwrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Y1
Wrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
X2
Unwrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Wrapping execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY2(int))
Y2
Unwrapping execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY2(int))
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY3(SomeType))
Y3
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY3(SomeType))
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.main(String[]))
```

Two things you notice here:

- The execution of the static `main(..)` method is logged. This would not happen with Spring AOP.
- The internal method calls are logged. This would also not happen with Spring AOP.

**Console output with Spring AOP:**

```
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX1())
X1
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX1())
Wrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
X2
Unwrapping execution(int de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodX2(String))
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Y1
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY1())
Wrapping execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY2(int))
Y2
Unwrapping execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY2(int))
Wrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY3(SomeType))
Y3
Unwrapping execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyImpl.methodY3(SomeType))
```

In most cases, Spring AOP is enough for Spring users. But if you need a more powerful approach in order to capture other types of pointcuts or e.g. internal, nested method calls, you would use [AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex. This was very helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to add additional parameters in `wrapperAdvice` method to be used by the advice?

Comment: Such as? Maybe you want to ask a new, complete question with sample code and an explanation.

Comment: Never mind. My question is answered by the available method `JoinPoint.getArgs()`. All set.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public abstract class ResourceProcessingService {
    protected <T> T processResource(Resource resource, Function<Reader, T> function) {
        try (InputStream fileInputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return function.apply(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new YourRuntimeException("Could not process resource: " + resource.getFilename() + ", " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In your concrete implementations you could now do something like this:

```
public class XImpl extends ResourceProcessingService implements X {

    public double performSomeResourceProcessing() {
        return processResource(yourResource, (reader) -> readTheResource(reader));
    }

    private double readTheResource(Reader reader) {
        // perform the resource reading
    }
}
```